# Set value to a random property from list

Tags: c#

Please check the code below. I am trying to set value to a random property of a int list. Problem is that even after `i` set `5` to a random list this value getting inserted to that property. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var TransactionList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
{
    TransactionList.Add(0);
}

var randTransaction = TransactionList.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();

//here i am trying to set 5 value to a random TrnasactionList but this not being set
randTransaction = 5;
```

Comment: randTransaction has type int, and it's value type not reference type.

Comment: @N1gthm4r3 - you are correct though I doubt OP will understand the implication of "value type not reference type"

Comment: Rather than finding `value` from `list` try getting `index` randomly, And then use `TransactionList[randomIndex] = 5`.

Comment: COOL with this, I like

Comment: Change `var TransactionList = new List<int>();` to `var TransactionList = new List<int>(59);` to speed up your code slightly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like below. `new Random().Next(0, 59);` will return value between `0` and `59`. Or you can better set it like `new Random().Next(0, TransactionList.Count);` for it to be dynamic with `list`.

`new Random().Next(minValue, maxValue);` The `maxValue` for the upper-bound in the `Next()` method is **exclusive**—the range includes `minValue`, `maxValue-1`, and all numbers in between.

```
var TransactionList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
{
    TransactionList.Add(0);
}

// var index = new Random().Next(0, 59);
// Below will work for dynamic length of list.
var index = new Random().Next(0, TransactionList.Count);
TransactionList[index] = 5;
```

Comment: Good idea, only recommendation I would have is to just TransactionList.Count in `.Next(0, 59)`

Comment: Why the -1? the max is exclusive so there will never be indexoutofboundexception if you only use .count

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for your suggestion. So far I was believing that `maxValue` is **included**. But it's **exclusive** and this will be really useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the original list getting sorted you could do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var transactionList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
        {
            //I initialized the list with i instead of 0 to better see sorting in place
            transactionList.Add(i);
        }

        transactionList.Sort(new RandomComparer());
        //changed it to 99 to spot it more easily
        transactionList[0] = 99;

        foreach (var i in transactionList)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

public class RandomComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    private Random _random = new Random();
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return _random.Next(-1, 2);
    }
}
```

See it in action:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NKuPdx

Comment: Little known fact: You can sort using a lambda: `transactionList.Sort((i, j) => random.Next(-1, 2));`. [Check this fork.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMPEIB)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - What? didn't know that, thx. only thought orderby can be used with lambda.

Comment: There's an overload of `List<T>.Sort` that takes in an instance of the `Comparison<T>` delegate - which is a delegate that takes in two `T` variables and returns an int - and since it's a delegate, you can use a lambda for it. I don't know why but a lot of developers I know don't know that fact (I myself have only learned about it about 3 years ago)

Answer (score 0):

randTransaction is "int" data type, which is primitive data type.

if you want to set randTransaction that reflect to it's object, just set the object it self

Comment: Unlike Java, in .Net we don't call them primitive types...

Comment: @ZoharPeled - just dropping this here :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive